# javascript: animate scrolling when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate page scrolling incrementally to different sections of the page when the user scrolls. So I wrote this code:

```
var $window = $(window);    
var sectionHeight = $window.height();
var animating = false;
var dir;
// initialize page position (0)
var pagePos = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    // current page position    
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether to animate up or down        
    dir = ((st > pagePos) ? '+=' : '-=');

    // animate 
    if (animating == false) {
        animating = true;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: dir+sectionHeight},500, function() {

            pagePos = $(window).scrollTop();    
            animating = false;
        }); 
    }
});
```

The problem is, I get a chained animation after my initial animation down, that animates the page back to the top. I'm not sure why, because it shouldn't animate unless 'animating' is set to false. It only gets set back to false when the animation is complete... right?

Comment: Interesting, inside the scroll function I added a line to show the status of 'animating' in a fixed div. It changes to true on a scroll, then flashes false, but ends up staying as true....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, I still don't know why it wouldn't work as it was coded, but here is the solution that worked for me- I was inspired by @sachleen's answer. Thanks sachleen.

I moved the scroll animation into a separate function, then on the callback to the animation function I used a setTimeout with the same duration as the animation to call another function that simply changed the 'animating' boolean back to false.

Answer (score 0):

One potential fix, although I'm sure somebody can come up with a better solution, is to disable it for a set period of time after it scrolls.

Relevant code:

```
var ct = new Date().getTime();

if (animating == false && new Date().getTime() > ct + 10)
```

This will only allow the animation to happen if at least 11ms have passed. Seems to work for values as low as 2. You don't really notice any lag in scrolling but again, I would not consider this an ideal solution.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/2/)